# String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan. C# and SQL Sserver

Tags: c#

I get an error

> String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan

I am coding in C# and can't seem to find out what the problem is. How to avoid this error and is `time(7)` datatype in my database.

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

This is my code where it's failing:

```
Classes.ClsBooking.BookingDataTable.InsertBooking(TimeSpan.Parse(string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "HH:mm")));
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Also, if you split this instruction in two: `var time = TimeSpan.Parse(string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "HH:mm"))` and then `Classes.ClsBooking.BookingDataTable.InsertBooking(time)`, which one is failing?

Comment: The "string.Format()" is redundant - you should just use DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm").  Or, alternatively, string.Format(DateTime.Now, "HH:mm").  By passing DateTime.Now.ToString() as the first parameter to string.Format(), you've already converted the date to a string (with whatever format your machine decides is its "default"), and then you're trying to reformat that string with "HH:mm" ..... the parameter will already be identified as a string, not the date that you're expecting it to be

Comment: this has nothing to do with the db, and all about the parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just want   `TimeSpan.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));`

Answer (score 1):

Use either:

```
string.Format(DateTime.Now, "HH:mm")
```

or, preferably

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
```

With what you are currently doing, you're passing a string (that's already formatted the date in the "default" format) as a parameter to "string.Format()", and then you're trying to tell "string.Format()" to reformat that string as "HH:mm".  That won't work, as the parameter will no longer be recognised as DateTime